# Check if a file belongs to a directory of directories

Tags: python, file, operating-system, directory

I have a directory which contains different *file* names. The other directory I have is a `directory of directories`, such that each directory has the same name of the filename in the first directory.

What I want to do is that I would like to check if a file exists in the directory of directories through its name.

While working on this I had to make different for-loops and was a bit confusing. Is there a simpler way to do that in Python?

Well, here's what I did so far:

```
import os

directory_of_files_path = '/home/user/directory_of_files'
directory_of_directories_path = '/home/user/directory_of_directories'
i = 0

for root_pairs, dirs_pairs, files_pairs in os.walk(directory_of_files_path):
    for root_aligned, dirs_aligned, files_aligned in os.walk(directory_of_directories_path):
        for file in files_pairs:
            for directory in dirs_aligned:
                filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)
                if filename == directory:
                    i = i + 1
```

As you can see, in the above code I was able to return the number of files included in the directory of directories (based on name). But, couldn't figure out to check those that are *not* included in the directory of directories.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example of what you are trying to do?  A (small!) set of directories and files, and what the expected output would be?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understood what you wanted to do but... here is my guess:
This is how I made the files and dirs

[image]

```
import os

dir_files = 'dir_files'
dir_dir = 'dir_dir'
i = 0

for rf, df, ff in os.walk(dir_files):
    ff2 = ff
    for rd, dd, fd in os.walk(dir_dir):
        for dirs in dd:
            if dirs + ".txt" in ff:
                i += 1
                ff2.remove(dirs + ".txt")
    print("There are ", i, "dirs that matches with the files")
    print("not found dir corresponding to {}".format(ff2))
```

> Output

[image]